# LINQ is converting string to special characters

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using this query to get data from database.

```
string nfc = "53f8372c";    
var temp = db.tempTable.AsNoTracking().Where(
               x =>
                   x.uid.Equals(nfc, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                   && x.ENDED == null
                   && x.STATUS.Equals(Constants.ACTIVE)
              );
```

The sql that is generated from this query is:

```
{SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
"Extent1"."uid" AS "uid", 
"Extent1"."ENDED" AS "ENDED", 
"Extent1"."STATUS" AS "STATUS", 
FROM "tempTable" "Extent1"
WHERE (("Extent1"."uid" = :p__linq__0) AND ("Extent1"."ENDED" IS NULL) AND ('Active' = "Extent1"."STATUS"))}
```

Why does it convert **53f8372c** to **:p__linq__0**?

Comment: `x.uid.Equals(nfc, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` nfc is variable and not string literal/constant?

Comment: That's a sql parameter.

Comment: @lad2025 its a variable

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi Exactly, and why it should be literal in SQL then?

Comment: On a side note you're not going to get case insensitive comparisons that way.  It's going to be completely based on the collation of your db, which is likely already case insensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just parameterizing the SQL. If you look at the parameters passed to the query, you'll see that `:p__linq__0` has a value of `53f8372c`.

This parameterization is helpful, as the server can cache the query plan and reuse it for the same query using different parameter values.

Comment: It's also better to use parameterized SQL to protect against SQL injection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query

Comment: @Marisa: Yes, although it's at least *less* of an issue when the SQL is being automatically generated - LINQ *could* have used a string value and escaped it if necessary. That would still allow for bugs to creep in in terms of escaping, of course.

Comment: @Marisa Parameterised queries have downsides too, for example they won't use filtered indexes. That's a bit of an edge case though.

Comment: @DavidG Good point. Generally in those cases the inlined value isn't variable or user input at all, but a hardcoded constant, so there is no risk of injection there.